# why my predictions is not correct , and accuracy = 00 , how can i train my data and fixe my problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

```
df_btc1=df_btc.sort_index(ascending=True,axis=0)
new_dataset=pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df_btc)),columns=['Date','Close'])
L=len(df_btc)

for i in range(0,len(df_btc1)):
    new_dataset["Date"][i]=df_btc1['Date'][i]
    new_dataset["Close"][i]=df_btc1["Close"][i]

#Normalize the Dataset
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
new_dataset.index=new_dataset.Date
new_dataset.drop("Date",axis=1,inplace=True)
final_dataset=new_dataset.values

train_data=final_dataset[0:L-300,:]
valid_data=final_dataset[L-300:,:]
scaled_data=scaler.fit_transform(final_dataset)

x_train_data,y_train_data=[],[]

for i in range(300,len(train_data)):
    x_train_data.append(scaled_data[i-300:i,0])
    y_train_data.append(scaled_data[i,0])
```

```
x_train_data,y_train_data=np.array(x_train_data),np.array(y_train_data)
x_train_data=np.reshape(x_train_data,(x_train_data.shape[0],x_train_data.shape[1],1))

#Build and train the LSTM model
lstm_model=Sequential()
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(x_train_data.shape[1],1)))
lstm_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
lstm_model.add(Dropout(0.2))

lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
lstm_model.add(Dropout(0.2))

lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50))
lstm_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
lstm_model.add(Dense(1))

inputs_data=new_dataset[len(new_dataset)-len(valid_data)-300:].values
inputs_data=inputs_data.reshape(-1,1)
inputs_data=scaler.transform(inputs_data)

lstm_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],optimizer='adam')
lstm_model.fit(x_train_data,y_train_data,epochs=5,batch_size=5,verbose=2)
```

Epoch 1/5
280/280 - 91s - loss: 0.3312 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 91s/epoch - 324ms/step
Epoch 2/5
280/280 - 85s - loss: 0.3344 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 85s/epoch - 305ms/step
Epoch 3/5
280/280 - 83s - loss: 0.3286 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 83s/epoch - 298ms/step
Epoch 4/5
280/280 - 84s - loss: 0.3267 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 84s/epoch - 299ms/step
Epoch 5/5
280/280 - 83s - loss: 0.3297 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 83s/epoch - 297ms/step
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f0f8c3e97d0>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UVsb.png)

Comment: Your output  layer should have a sigmoid activation.

Comment: When I use sigmoid activation I found error I don't why, that why I use it like this

Comment: You seem to be using a classification loss and model, while your task seems to be regression

Comment: What I have to do in this case please can u help me in code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okey sir, I wanna do prediction to cryptocurrencies, I used 2000 in data 1700 for train and 300 for test, I wanna calculate loss and accuracy but I found loss stay fixé and accuracy zero,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loss `loss='binary_crossentropy'` is adapted for binary classification problems but not for time series prediction problems.
For time series prediction, you should use mean square error.
Also, you cannot use `accuracy` for problems that are not classifiction, so just remove the `metrics` from your code, giving:

```
lstm_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer='adam')
```

Comment: hello Pierrotb1 ,i have do that i found this Epoch 1/20
50/50 - 20s - loss: 0.0012 - 20s/epoch - 393ms/step
Epoch 2/20
50/50 - 13s - loss: 2.3794e-04 - 13s/epoch - 262ms/step
Epoch 3/20
50/50 - 12s - loss: 2.0763e-04 - 12s/epoch - 241ms/step
... ,but my professor told me that i have to found a loss value between 0.99 and 0.1 converge to 0 , and also to do plot to show that loss converge to 0 and accuracy converge to 1 ,who can i do that please.

Comment: You obtain a low loss, converging to 0 (about 1e-4), showing that the code is working. To make a plot of the loss: `plt.plot(lstm_model.history.history['loss'])` where `plt` is the module `matplotlib.pyplot`

Comment: i do that the plot converge to 0 from the beginning is that normal, because we have to found convergence after some epoch and not from the beginning , how can i talk to u and send u pircture of this plot please , if u have linkedin and think u

Comment: The loss is very low immediately after only one epoch because the model converges very fast ; you can see the loss before the training by doing `lstm_model.evaluate(x_train_data,y_train_data)` (before `lstm_model.fit`) and you will see it is not close to 0.

Comment: lstm_model.evaluate(x_train_data,y_train_data) 44/44 [==============================] - 3s 64ms/step - loss: 8.7484e-05
8.748426625970751e-05 no that was i found when i use this function